# android webiew button event

Tags: android, wordpress, button, webview

i am creating webview based app.
the site is base on wordpress and the clients will see the touch version.

in the comments of any post, there is option to add image, when i am clicking on it at chrome, it directing me to pick a picture, but when i am clicking on it at the app nothing happened, this are the webview setting:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

thanks.

Comment: you have not searched your question over stackoverflow before posting